# Aws cloudformation - how to use a string parameter to prevent repetitive use of same string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

1.
In my code, string "HelloWorldApi" uses a lots as a ref.
Is it possbile to use my defined parameter "APIName" to replace the repeat string "HelloWorldApi", 
so that I don't need to update those string 1 by 1 when I make another stack and rename the API?

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    
    "Parameters": {
      "APIName": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "HelloWorldApi"
      }
    },
    "Resources": {
      "HelloWorldApi": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
        "Properties": {
          "Name": "hello-api",
          "Description": "API used for practice",
          "FailOnWarnings": true
        }
      },
      "APIAuthorizer" :{
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer",
        "Properties" : {
            "RestApiId" : {
              "Ref": "HelloWorldApi"
            }
          }
      },
      "BannerDBModel": {
          "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
          "Properties" : {
              "Name" : "postBannerModel",
              "RestApiId" : {
                "Ref": "HelloWorldApi"
              },
              "Schema" : {
                "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                "title": "ProductsInputModel",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "url": {"type": "string"}
                }                
              }
           }
      },
      "PostRequestValidator": {
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator",
        "Properties" : {
            "Name" : "PostRequestValidator",
            "RestApiId" : {
                "Ref": "HelloWorldApi"
            }
        }
      },
      "BannerResource": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {
                "Ref": "HelloWorldApi"
            },
            "ParentId": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "HelloWorldApi",
                    "RootResourceId"
                ]
            },
            "PathPart": "banner"
        }
      },
      "getBannerMethod": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
        "DependsOn": ["HelloWorldApi"],
        "Properties": {
          "RestApiId": {
            "Ref": "HelloWorldApi"
          },
          "ResourceId": {
            "Ref": "BannerResource"
          },
          "HttpMethod": "GET",
          "AuthorizationType": "NONE"
        }
      },
      "Deployment": {
          "DependsOn": ["HelloWorldApi"],
          "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
          "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {
              "Ref": "HelloWorldApi"
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

2.
Lets say I have already created a stack through below code, if the default value of APIName is accidentally set to HelloWorld which is different from original version, will the error shows instantly after I run updateStack?
 What will happen then? Another API HelloWorld being created?

Updated Code according to the comment

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    
    "Parameters": {
      "RestAPI": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "HelloWorldApi"
      }
    },
    "Resources": {
      "RestAPI": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
        "Properties": {
          "Name": "hello-api",
          "Description": "API used for practice",
          "FailOnWarnings": true
        }
      },
      "APIAuthorizer" :{
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer",
        "Properties" : {
            "RestApiId" : {
              "Ref": "RestAPI"
            }
          }
      },
      "BannerDBModel": {
          "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
          "Properties" : {
              "Name" : "postBannerModel",
              "RestApiId" : {
                "Ref": "RestAPI"
              },
              "Schema" : {
                "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                "title": "ProductsInputModel",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "url": {"type": "string"}
                }                
              }
           }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reuse this template you should rename the resource named `HelloWorldApi` to something more generic.

If you currently renamed the resource and attempted to redeploy it would remove any resources that are associated with the `HelloWorldApi` API as well as the API itself whilst redeploying the API again.

The string you're using is referencing the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource not the value in the `APIName` parameter. If you updated this parameter value at the moment it would not affect the stack as it appears as though it is not used.

In summary the referencing of the string `HelloWorldApi` in `Resources` is referring to the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resources logical name.

Ensure the resources do not share the same name as the parameters.

The template would look like the below

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    
    "Parameters": {
      "RestAPIName": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "HelloWorldApi"
      }
    },
    "Resources": {
      "RestAPI": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
        "Properties": {
          "Name": { "Ref": "RestAPIName" },
          "Description": "API used for practice",
          "FailOnWarnings": true
        }
      },
      "APIAuthorizer" :{
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer",
        "Properties" : {
            "RestApiId" : {
              "Ref": "RestAPI"
            }
          }
      },
      "BannerDBModel": {
          "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
          "Properties" : {
              "Name" : "postBannerModel",
              "RestApiId" : {
                "Ref": "RestAPI"
              },
              "Schema" : {
                "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                "title": "ProductsInputModel",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "url": {"type": "string"}
                }                
              }
           }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: so how should I modify the code to achieve the reuse purpose?

Comment: @CCCC I would suggest that you name your resources what they are not what they're for. So for example `HelloWorldApi` resource would become RestAPI.

Anything that is configurable set in parameters

Comment: should I also change below?
"RestApiId" : {
              "Ref": "HelloWorldApi"
}
?

Comment: The `Ref` here would become the name of your Rest API Resource. So if you resources logical name is `RestApi` i would be  "RestApiId" : { "Ref": "RestApi" }

Comment: I updated the code above. please help to see if this is what you mean